# Present and dismiss view modally in tabbed application using swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've created a tabbed application and am able to present a view modally using the code below, however, I'm stuck on dismissing the view and displaying the tab bar and first view controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let signUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.rootViewController = signUpViewController
```

Comment: You do not present anything modally in your code. You replace whatever is the `rootViewController` in your app (I guess the tab bar controller) with your `signUpViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside that `signUpViewController` do this after giving that tabBarController a storyboard identifier in IB

```
let tab = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"tab") 
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tab
```

**OR**

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController = tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You should present your modal vc over you tab bar vc

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let signUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
signUpViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
signUpViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
self.window.rootViewController.present(myModalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

(if self.window.rootViewController - your tab bar view controller)

And in this case you can use ***dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)*** method in modal vc to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TabBarViewController`, do the following when presenting `SignUpViewController`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SignUpViewController")
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true)
```

and when dismissing, simply call the dismiss code from `SignUpViewController`

e.g. `dismissViewControllerAnimated`